# iOS Facebook login - signedRequest field

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm looking for the `signedRequest` field ([on this link, under Response objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)) on iOS. We need this signed request object, which is specific to our application, and not the accessToken, which is specific to the user.

On web, the developer can do the following:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    /* response looks like: 
    { status: 'connected', 
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'} 
    }
    */
}
```

I don't see an analogous property in [FBSession](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession), [FBAccessTokenData](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBAccessTokenData), or [FBAppCall](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBAppCall) APIs.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: what's your final purpose? If you need to check whether the user is logged in there are other methods in the SDK

Comment: AFAIK the signed_request is only available for web apps. As @GabrielePetronella asked – what do you need it for?

Comment: I have exactly the same wish and the property is needed to verify that the UserId is not a fake and to do the verification without a separate server-side call to Fb servers. When users login with Web/JS we send the property to the serverside, but when an iOS client logs in we don't see how we can get the `signed_request` property and send its value to the server.